# Shared axis labels with independent scale

Tags: altair, vega-lite

When facet/concat-ing charts, I would like the axis labels to be shared (so only 1 label per column/row, here: Horsepower), but the scale to be independent. Is this possible?

I thought a combination of `resolve_axis` and `resolve_scale` would be the way to go, as the title is a part of `Axis`, but I didn't get it to work.

I'm also wondering what `resolve_axis` actually does different than `resolve_scale`, anyone has an example?

```py
base = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle().encode(
    x=alt.X('Horsepower:Q',),
    y=alt.Y('Miles_per_Gallon:Q'),
    color='Origin:N',
    row=alt.Row('Origin:N'),
).properties(
    width=200, height=100
)

base.resolve_axis(
    x='shared' # doesn't do anything obvious
).resolve_scale(
    x='independent'
)
```

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

I found a hacky way to do this, by misusing the facet header:

```py
base = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x=alt.X('Horsepower:Q',),
    y=alt.Y('Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
           axis=alt.Axis(title=''),),
    color='Origin:N',
    column=alt.Column('Origin:N', header=alt.Header(title='Miles_per_Gallon')),
).properties(
    width=200, height=200
).configure_header(
    labelExpr="['Origin',datum.value]",
    titleOrient='left'
)
display(base.resolve_scale(y='shared'))
display(base.resolve_scale(y='independent'))
```

[image: plot1]
[image: plot2]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to do what you're hoping for (independent scales with only a single outer axis title) via scale and guide resolution.

As to your question of the difference between `resolve_scale` and `resolve_axis`, an example may help.

Here's a chart with independent y **scale**:

```python
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
source = data.cars()

base = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle().encode(
    x=alt.X('Horsepower:Q',),
    y=alt.Y('Miles_per_Gallon:Q'),
    color='Origin:N',
    column=alt.Column('Origin:N'),
).properties(
    width=150, height=150
)

base.resolve_scale(
    y='independent'
)
```

[image]

And here's one with independent y **axis**:

```python
base.resolve_axis(
    y='independent'
)
```

[image]

In both cases, each chart gets its own axis (because independent scales imply independent axes), but only with an independent scale do the axes scales differ from each other.

Comment: Thanks.Fyi, you mixed scale<>axis in the 2nd code block.